# Microservice Clients Circular Dependency

Tags: php, node.js, microservices

In a Microservice architecture, using client packages to communicate between services, we ran into an issue where two client packages depend on each other, creating a circular dependency.

We are trying to figure out the best solution for this and I'm wondering if anyone would be able to help or point us in the right direction.

Here is the scenario:

- Two services, Car and Insurance
- Two client packages, CarClient and InsuranceClient.

Whenever any service needs to communicate with the Car service, it should use the CarClient package to do so. And whenever any service needs to communicate with the Insurance service, it should use the InsuranceClient package.

The CarClient package has a data transfer object (DTO) `Car` where one of its properties is `insurance`. The type for this property is a DTO available in the InsuranceClient package, `CarInsurance`.

The issue is when the `CarInsurance` DTO needs to access an enum available in the CarClient package, `CarTypeEnum`. Now we have the two packages depending on each other.

[image: Microservice Clients Circular Dependency]

Possible solutions I can think of:

1. This is due to a bad design. Redesign the services and packages to prevent this circular dependency.
2. Move the enums into separate packages, therefore, both clients can depend on these packages but the clients wont't depend on each other.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are Car and Insurance two separate clients/services? Could you merge the two? I'm just a newbie and I don't know the details of your applications but if the two services are already dependent on one another, why not get everything under one roof?

Comment: The insurance service does multiple tasks that are unrelated to cars, including other types of insurance (ex.: home insurance). The idea of a micro service is to decouple these tasks into their own repo (service) so we can code and deploy more effectively. However, this comes at a price since it does add a bit of complexity.

Comment: Are you talking about a `package` in the Java sense? Because then why is circular dependency a problem in that case?

Comment: Are you trying to make your service overwork? something like registering a car and adding insurance plan to it in a single call? then may be you would like to separate the two responsibility one is register the car and then add insurance plan to it, this is just an example, if you can explain the situation, I may able to give some better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be sharing any code between services since that defeats the whole purpose of them being 100% independent.

In a MS architecture a CarDTO would only have properties related to a car. If you want information about insurance that would be a separate call to the insurance service to get an InsuranceDTO that has only insurance properties.

When calling either service you would use some key to tie it all together. I.e. you would call the car service with a customerId that you got from the customer service and your CarDTO would have a carId, then you can call the insurance service with customerId/carId to get the InsuranceDTO.

Comment: We are fetching the insurance service to get the insurance, but we are adding that object to a property in the Car dto. That's why we need the type. But let's say we don't do that, how do we handle the enum problem? The insurance service needs to know what type of car it needs to create an insurance for, therefore, it will receive a car type id with the payload. That's why the dto has that property. Since the dto lives in the insurance client, that client depends on the car client to access the car type enum. If we don't do that, we would need to duplicate enums between these repos.

Comment: @crabbly That's exactly why you are running into issues. You are trying to tightly couple the two services. The DTOs should be completely separate. Imagine if you change a shared class and introduce a breaking change -- now you need to rebuild everything that uses it and redeploy everything that uses it and you may miss something. Imagine if you have 1000s of services. A change to a shared class would mean redeploying everything.

Comment: @crabbly In MS you should be able to deploy a single service and not break anything or have to redeploy anything other then that service. A breaking change in MS is "not allowed" and you need to design your services with "version control" in mind. For example, we use content type negotiation on ours and it works great although it is a bit more complicated to get right. At the end of the day /cars/v1 would have your current version and /v2 would have the one with breaking changes and services can migrate to v2 as they need.

Comment: P.S. it is fine to "copy & paste" DTOs in MS. It's just json after all. You probably wouldn't want to share a server DTO with a client DTO anyways since they'll likely be different in the real world (annotations and such).

Comment: When we change a DTO, we are changing the Api contract, therefore, we should expect things to break no matter what. That's why we do versioning. To prevent that from happening. So, that is not an issue for us, and its unrelated to the problem above.

The issue is really just trying to reuse those DTOs and Enums. So in your opinion, we should just duplicate them on each repo. I guess that's a way to do it, and would indeed fix the dependency.

Comment: @crabbly When I first started with MS, I had the same questions you do and did a lot of research and you'll find most people who started out with shared classes abandoned them because they end up needing small differences everywhere and introduce dependencies.  You'll also find out down the road that accepting "breaking no matter what" will come back to bite you :).

Comment: We have been using MS for a while, not a small environment. I was just wondering how other people worked around the same problem. Thanks for posting your opinion on this. I'm not sure what you mean by the "breaking" comment though. Its pretty obvious that when you change any Api (rest services, classes, modules...), you should expect things to break unless is backwards compatible. That's a different topic also. Thanks again for your post, I'll wait for more opinions on this before marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: @crabbly I just meant in MS, you should not deploy "breaking changes", or even in any sort of public rest api. Say you have 100 services that call "ServiceA". If you make a breaking change in ServiceA, you need to update 100 services all at once and redeploy them all. With MS, your change should be in a "v2" endpoint so you don't break anything and have to migrate all 100 services right away. The whole point of MS is that you can deploy ServiceA by itself and have every other service still work, even with breaking changes.

Comment: @crabbly if your "MS" environment requires that you update and redeploy 100s of services just for a change in ServiceA, then you aren't doing MS, you're doing a monolithic application that you overly complicated by breaking it up into a bunch of services :). Main advantage of MS is 100% independence for code and deployments. If you aren't doing that, then there really isn't a point to MS. It's just complicating things at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I read the long conversation in comments of previous answer and I would like to make an addition which is kind of supporting the idea of "just duplicate them on each repo".

If you design your services based on the idea of DDD(domain driven design) you may be aware that the same concept/entity could mean different things in different domains.

That means "insurance" inside the CarService may have -depending on the domain/requirements- quite some different attributes then the one in InsuranceService. That is why the insurance concept in CarService should have its own dto which should be totally free from InsuranceService's insurance definition.

Comment: Yea, in some cases that seems to be the right approach. Specially with the Enums. In other scenarios looks like we should probably eliminate the dependency in the client level, and let the service handle the relations internally.

Answer (score 0):

You could just not use the CarTypeEnum in your Insurance service. Just use a CarId. When you need to know the type, just ask the car service for that information.

Comment: The enum is useful when using the car type for business logic. Instead of reacting code to static numbers, its better to use enums instead.